# Wordpress site won't load - 404 - File or directory not found

Tags: php, wordpress

I copied a working Wordpress site from one server (Windows 2008 Server, IIS v7.0) to another (Windows 2008 r2 Server, IIS v7.5), configured exactly the same in respect to file permissions on all the directories on both sites and IIS configuration on both servers and I get a 404 when I attempt to load the site from the new server.  I've tried several suggestions posted on the web without success.  Nothing loads, I get the 404 error from everything, so it's not a permalink thing, it never gets that far.  So what is the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered my own question - turns out I fat-fingered the php directory in the path environment variable when I installed php v7.1.11, added an extra character.  The site could not find the php installation hence the 404 error.  Fixed the path, all works as expected.